# Virtual Data Room service with anonymity login management

Tags: share, sharefile

Please can someone recommend a virtual data room service which allows to create user login based on non-real email?

To be more clear this is a scenario:
I created data room named '123 5th Avenue' and want to set up log-in on this folder which will be distributed to many people. Instead of sharing this folder to the real emails of the people who need access to the folder, I prefer to create just one login/user like this: 5thAve@mydomain.com with appropriate folder permissions and distribute it to those ones who need it.

I know that ShareFile by Citrix allows this but it is too expensive for me. It's welcomed if someone can suggest any service based on own knowledge or experience.

Thank you!

Comment: Many services that I tried allow to create login on a data room folder using real emails only (confirmation is required). I am looking for the possibility where I can create a user with non-real email which will be used to log in to a specific folder.